# Setting up the integrand of a sum of iid random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

In relation to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4207396/963790), why is the integrand

$$f(x,z-x)=4x(1+x-z)$$

when trying to get the pdf of $Z=X+Y$ as

$$f_Z(z)=\int 4x(1+x-z)dx$$

if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables where $X$ has a pdf given by $f_X(x)=2xI_{(0,1)}(x)$ and $Y$ has a pdf given by $f_Y(y)=2(1-y)I_{(0,1)}(y))$?

Comment: 1) If $ Z = z, X = x$, what would be the value of $Y$? What is the pdf for this case? 2) If $ Z = z$, calculate the pdf by summing up over all possible values of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

And of course, it is immediate by just hitting the right prompt on the YT archives. In this case, [this MIT lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2M4LNSeIn4).

The deal is to integrate over lines of constant $z=x+y,$ and this is done with this recipe:

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\rm dx$$

which gets rid of the $y$ within the integral, and will result on a function of $z$ after integrating out $x$. This is the convolution

$$(f_X*f_Y)_Z(z)$$

The recipe is not obvious, and results from deriving the joint pdf of $X$ and $Z$ and then integrating $X$ out to get the marginal pdf of $Z$ (the desired result). The joint pdf $f_{(X, Z)}$ will call for a conditional pdf, i.e. $f_{Z\mid X}(z\mid x)$ times $f_X(x).$ The crux is to see that

$$f_{Z\mid X}(z\mid x)=f_Y(z-x)$$

which is arrived noting the iid premise.

The rest is just mindless

$$f_X(x)f_Y(y)= 2x\left(2(1-y)\right)=f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)=2x\left(2(1-(z-x) \right)$$